# How to include hidden files in python distutils?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py, hidden-files

My package has a hidden directory I want to distribute as package data. I include the following in `distutils.setup(...)`:

```
[...]
package_data={'mypkg': ['.hg/*']},
[...]
```

However this syntax does not work: when I run `python setup.py install`, the directory `.hg` is not included in the package. I believe the problem is in the directory name `.hg`, because if I replace `.hg` with `hg`, then the following will work as expected.

```
[...]
package_data={'mypkg': ['hg/*']},
[...]
```

Unfortunately the directory name has to be `.hg` for Mercurial to work. Is there a workaround to this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. `package_data={'mypkg': ['../.git/*']}` included `.git/*` in `sdist`, `bdist_egg` and `bdist_wheel`. May be you need to upgrade `setuptools`?

Comment: @phd Thanks for your comment, I have the latest version of `setuptools`. What version are you using?

Comment: `setuptools 38.4.0`

Comment: @phd Sorry for the newbieness, but I used from `distutils.core import setup` instead of `from setuptools import setup`. This made the difference. If you could please take the time to formulate this as an answer I will make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work with `setuptools` (instead of `distutils`):

```
package_data={'mypkg': ['../.git/*']}
```

includes `.git/*` (non-recursive) in `sdist`, `bdist_egg` and `bdist_wheel`.